# !is.na creates NAs in other columns

Tags: r, dataframe, na

In the midst of merging several data sets, I'm trying to remove all rows of a data frame that have a missing value for one particular variable (I want to keep the NAs in some of the other columns for the time being). I used the following line:

```
data.frame <- data.frame[!is.na(data.frame$year),]
```

This successfully removes all rows with NAs for `year`, (and no others), but the other columns, which previously had data, are now entirely NAs. In other words, non-missing values are being converted to NA. Any ideas as to what's going on here? I've tried these alternatives and got the same outcome:

```
data.frame <- subset(data.frame, !is.na(year))

data.frame$x <- ifelse(is.na(data.frame$year) == T, 1, 0);
data.frame <- subset(data.frame, x == 0)
```

Am I using `is.na` incorrectly? Are there any alternatives to `is.na` in this scenario? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

***Edit*** Here is code that should reproduce the issue:

```
#data
tc <- read.csv("http://dl.dropbox.com/u/4115584/tc2008.csv")
frame <- read.csv("http://dl.dropbox.com/u/4115584/frame.csv")

#standardize NA codes
tc[tc == "."] <- NA
tc[tc == -9] <- NA

#standardize spatial units
colnames(frame)[1] <- "loser"
colnames(frame)[2] <- "gainer"
frame$dyad <- paste(frame$loser,frame$gainer,sep="")
tc$dyad <- paste(tc$loser,tc$gainer,sep="")
drops <- c("loser","gainer")
tc <- tc[,!names(tc) %in% drops]
frame <- frame[,!names(frame) %in% drops]
rm(drops)

#merge tc into frame
data <- merge(tc, frame, by.x = "year", by.y = "dyad", all.x=T, all.y=T) #year column is duplicated in       this process. I haven't had this problem with nearly identical code using other data.

rm(tc,frame)

#the first column in the new data frame is the duplicate year, which does not actually contain years.   I'll rename it.
colnames(data)[1] <- "double"

summary(data$year) #shows 833 NA's

summary(data$procedur) #note that at this point there are non-NA values

#later, I want to create 20 year windows following the events in the tc data. For simplicity, I want to remove cases with NA in the year column.

new.data <- data[!is.na(data$year),]

#now let's see what the above operation did
summary(new.data$year) #missing years were successfully removed
summary(new.data$procedur) #this variable is now entirely NA's
```

Comment: give us a reproducible data please. And please don't name your `data.frame` as `data.frame`. As there is already a function named `data.frame`.

Comment: @Arun But can he named his `data.frame` `function`, or is there already a `data.frame` called `function` ? :)

Comment: :) my head's spinning. lol.

Comment: sorry, I thought it might be something that could answered conceptually. I made an edit with code and data that should reproduce the problem.

Comment: @davy, have you checked your `data` after the `merge` step?

Comment: @Arun I also thought the `merge` operation was the culprit since something isn't working quite perfectly in that step, but I did `summary(data$procedur)` after every step, and the data are converted to NA's after the `new.data <- data[!is.na(data$year),]` command. Is it possible that something is going wrong with `merge` that would cause a problem that isn't manifest until I try to remove the NA's?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the actual problem is with your `merge`.

After you merge and have the data in `data`, if you do:

```
# > table(data$procedur, useNA="always")

#   1      2      3      4      5      6   <NA> 
# 122    112    356     59     39     19 192258
```

You see there are these many (`122+112...+19`) values for `data$procedur`. But, all these values are corresponding to `data$year = NA`.

```
> all(is.na(data$year[!is.na(data$procedur)]))
# [1] TRUE # every value of procedur occurs where year = NA
```

So, basically, all values of `procedur` are also removed because you removed those rows checking for `NA` in `year`.

To solve this problem, I think you should use `merge` as:

```
merge(tc, frame, all=T) # it'll automatically calculate common columns
# also this will not result in duplicated year column.
```

Check if this merge gives you the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

Try `complete.cases`:

```
data.frame.clean <- data.frame[complete.cases(data.frame$year),]
```

...though, as noted above, you may want to pick a more descriptive name.

Comment: the usage of `is.na` is right. So, I suspect this would do any different.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But yes, the outcome is exactly the same.